# memory addressesing

Tags: memory-address

For example we are in Windows XP platform, we have program A on ollydbg and we look on the instruction x. it has the address 0x11111111(for example).if i take the program A and run in ollydbg on a different computer with the same platform the instruction x will have the same address 0x11111111? 
So my question is : Are memory addresses changing every time the Program A runs? or are them changed in a different computer or platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the architecture but you should never rely on these addresses being the same. For practical purposes the answer is no.

To answer your comment, exploits have to find out where they are. A simple way for this is to make a call and pop the return address, like this:

```
  call test_eip
test_eip:
  pop eax
```

In this case, you'll have the instruction pointer in `eax`. This is usefull for determining where the injected code is.

Of course you'll have to get to the point where this is run, mostly using a buffer overflow exploit.

Wikipedia - as always - provides a great explanation and a lot of links to look after: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow

Comment: thanks alot for answering.
So how an exploit(based on buffer overflow) can run a shellcode(assume no protection) on the stack where the starting address of the shellcode must overwrite the return address and while we cant rely on them. how this is possible? this is the thing i cant get.

Comment: yes but the problem is : how test_esp can be run if i dont redirect the return address to something to execute it. i must first know an address. and for example i cant "gdb-it" on the vulnerable program in a remote computer. a general question: how that well known exploit-tools work. have them a constant variable with a return addres? am asking too much i know but i think this is gap am falling,. i need a guid propably for this but if you can answer me i will appreciate it. ty again

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is a Virtual address. The CPU contains special registers that can only be seen by the operating system; these registers control the mapping of virtual memory to physical memory. Every time the OS switches to a different process, it reprograms these registers so that the program thinks its memory is always in the same place.

Comment: so an exploit depends on that virtual addresses.see my comment below.
ty for answering.

Answer (score 0):

On the same OS version with the same executable, you will probably, but not certainly, see the same code addresses. Different OS versions, less likely.

Answer (score 0):

Windows PE binaries are not position independent, this means, they need to assume a fixed address to execute from.  Microsoft does this to improve execution performance (at the cost of load time penalties).

Your binary will always execute from where it wants, DLL's however may become relocated if their preferrered address is allready used by some other code.

Relocation is transparent to you, what happens is the Windows binary loader modifies your code and fixes all of the addresses so they work in the new location.